# java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not execute method of the activity (using jdom libraries)

Tags: android, import, libraries, illegalstateexception, jdom

I'm writing an app and i need to parse some xml file so i decided to use the jdom libraries. In my android project i followed this step: Project>properties>java build path> libraries> add external jars and i select the jdom libraries.

Now i have this logcat output:

```
02-06 13:13:28.197: E/AndroidRuntime(7912): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
02-06 13:13:28.197: E/AndroidRuntime(7912): java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not execute method of the activity
02-06 13:13:28.197: E/AndroidRuntime(7912):     at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:3044)
02-06 13:13:28.197: E/AndroidRuntime(7912):     at  android.view.View.performClick(View.java:3511)
02-06 13:13:28.197: E/AndroidRuntime(7912):     at   android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:14105)
02-06 13:13:28.197: E/AndroidRuntime(7912):     at        android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:605)
02-06 13:13:28.197: E/AndroidRuntime(7912):     at  android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
02-06 13:13:28.197: E/AndroidRuntime(7912):     at  android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
02-06 13:13:28.197: E/AndroidRuntime(7912):     at   android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4575)
02-06 13:13:28.197: E/AndroidRuntime(7912):     at  java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
02-06 13:13:28.197: E/AndroidRuntime(7912):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
02-06 13:13:28.197: E/AndroidRuntime(7912):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:789)
02-06 13:13:28.197: E/AndroidRuntime(7912):     at  com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:556)
02-06 13:13:28.197: E/AndroidRuntime(7912):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
02-06 13:13:28.197: E/AndroidRuntime(7912): Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
02-06 13:13:28.197: E/AndroidRuntime(7912):     at  java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
02-06 13:13:28.197: E/AndroidRuntime(7912):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
02-06 13:13:28.197: E/AndroidRuntime(7912):     at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:3039)
02-06 13:13:28.197: E/AndroidRuntime(7912):     ... 11 more
 02-06 13:13:28.197: E/AndroidRuntime(7912): Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org.jdom2.input.SAXBuilder
02-06 13:13:28.197: E/AndroidRuntime(7912):     at  com.tesi.AR.Anteprima.save(Anteprima.java:53)
02-06 13:13:28.197: E/AndroidRuntime(7912):     ... 14 more
```

when the app execute this line of code:

```
    //Creazione documento xml 
    SAXBuilder builder = new SAXBuilder();
    Document document = builder.build(confFile);
    Element rootElement = document.getRootElement();
    Element ar = new Element("AR");
    rootElement.addContent(ar);

    Element target = new Element ("TARGET");
    target.setText(targetPathFile.getAbsolutePath());
    ar.addContent(target);

    Element contenuto = new Element("CONTENUTO");
    contenuto.setText(contenutiPathFile.getAbsolutePath());
    ar.addContent(contenuto);

    Element scalatura = new Element("SCALATURA");
    scalatura.setText(String.valueOf(scale));
    ar.addContent(scalatura);

    //scrittura sul file xml
    XMLOutputter outputter = new XMLOutputter();
    outputter.output(document, new FileOutputStream(confFile));
```

thanks for your attention.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solve it in Project>properties>java build path>order and export ticking the libraries

Answer (score 0):

Have you followed the instructions here: [Including JDOM in your project](https://github.com/hunterhacker/jdom/wiki/JDOM2-and-Android#wiki-including-jdom-in-your-project)

Specifically, did you put the JDOM jar in your libs/ folder in your project?